# Git commit and push error Changes not staged for commit:

Tags: git

I have problem with commit and push the client, I get this error:

```
On branch VersionOne
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/VersionOne'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   client (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Before I was pushing my files from the client its self, but I create backend file and could not commit it from the clinet, so I create new branch in top level directory and add both of them, the client not pushed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Changes+not+staged+for+commit+modified+content

Comment: Hi, I tried some but didn't work, note that I'm new to git staff and I don't know client is submoudel, I just want to commit and push both client and backend file, the first branch I made can only commit the files inside client, can you please help me

Comment: Did you make sure the type of file you were trying to add wasn't in a .gitignore?

Comment: yes I ensure that it's not in .gitignore

Comment: Looks like `client` is a submodule. Follow the link that user phd posted in their comment.

Comment: I try alot of staff but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem, by moving to the client folder which is the inner repository or submodel and delete all the git files by  going to :

1. cmd in widnows
2. cd to my project
3. run del `/F /S /Q /A .git`
4. Init git again in the root folder and puch everything

**NOTE: MAKE SURE TO BACKUP EVERYTHING FOR ANY CASE**